# Proof for formula for number of divisors

Tags: prime-factorization, natural-numbers

For any natural number $n>1$, with factorization 
$$
n = q_1^{\alpha_1}q_2^{\alpha_2}q_3^{\alpha_3}....q_m^{\alpha_m}
$$
we can find the number of divisors by using the formula, 
$$
(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)....(\alpha_m+1)
$$
How do I find this formula. Is there a proof for it?

Comment: Do you know multiplicative functions?

Comment: Try it for some small values of $\alpha$. ... say $n=6$.

Comment: @s1mple how do i use them as a proof?

Comment: @Kirito please see the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove this first consider the number of the form $n=p^{\alpha}$. The divisors are $1,p,p^2,\cdots, p^{\alpha}$, i.e. $d(p^{\alpha})=\alpha+1$. Now, consider $n=p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}$, where $p,q$ are co-prime. The divisors would be : $$1,p,p^2,\cdots p^{\alpha}$$

$$q,pq,p^2q,\cdots,p^{\alpha}q$$
 Similarly, upto:
$$q^{\beta},pq^{\beta},\cdots,p^{\alpha}q^{\beta}$$
In this case, $d(p^{\alpha}q^{\beta})=(\alpha+1)(\beta+1)$. Hence $d(n)$ is multiplicative function.

For any natural number $n>1$, with prime factorization , where $q_1,q_2\cdots q_m$ are distinct primes and $m\ge1 $
$$
n = q_1^{\alpha_1}q_2^{\alpha_2}q_3^{\alpha_3}....q_m^{\alpha_m}
$$
we can find the number of divisors by using the formula, 
$$
(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)....(\alpha_m+1)
$$

Comment: If this answer was helpful for you, please consider clicking the checkmark. Glad to help!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.